# Improve M:N Top Query so that it is indexable on Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a ticket system which has a pretty easy schema for my Azure SQL v150 Database.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tickets](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TicketComments](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,

    [TicketId] [int] NOT NULL,
)
```

For me, in my case, I need to know from each ticket which is the first comment and which is the last comment.

| TicketId | FirstCommentId | LatestCommentId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2003 | 9658 |

My wish now would be to be able to implement everything without helper columns and still be performant.

In principle, this is not a problem; I have already managed to do this using joins or a cross apply. But the performance is already very poor with 100,000 entries.

Do I have any chance to get rid of my joins to solve this with indexed views?

Comment: what do you mean by "first" and "last"?  Is that based on the `[created_on]` column, i.e. earliest comment by date, and latest comment by date?  Or is that "earliest comment by `[ticket_comment_id]`" and "latest comment by `[ticket_comment_id]`."  They amount to the same thing if comments are always inserted in the same date they occur, i.e. a comment on `2012-01-01` is inserted into the table before a comment on `2012-01-02` is inserted.  Also, it would be helpful if you showed the "joins" you're using to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a leap of faith and assume by "first" and "last" you mean earliest comment date and latest comment date per ticket.

I took the liberty of creating a [minimal verifiable example](/mcve) to show I approached solving the problem.

First off, the two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ticket]
(
    [ticket_id]         int                 NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ticket_comment]
(
    [ticket_comment_id] int                 NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(-2147483647,1)
    , [ticket_id]       int                 NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES [dbo].[ticket]
        (
            [ticket_id]
        )
    , [created_on]      datetimeoffset(7)   NOT NULL
    , INDEX ix_ticket_comment
        (
              [ticket_id]
            , [created_on]
        )
);
```

Notice in the `[dbo].[ticket_comment]` table, I've created a non-clustered index on `[ticket_id]` and `[created_on]`.

Here, I'm inserting some sample data so we can see how the query works.  It's 1,000 tickets, each with 1,000 random values in `created_on`:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ticket]
(
    [ticket_id]
)
SELECT
    gs.[value]
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1,1000,1) gs

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ticket_comment]
(
      [ticket_id]
    , [created_on]
)
SELECT t.[ticket_id]
    , DATEADD(SECOND, CONVERT(int, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(6), 0), CONVERT(datetimeoffset(7), '2001-01-01T00:00:00.000', 126))
FROM [dbo].[ticket] t
CROSS JOIN GENERATE_SERIES(1, 1000, 1) gs;
GO
```

Since you're on Azure SQL Database, you'll have access to the `GENERATE_SERIES` relational operator which is also available on SQL Server 2022+.

The query to get the results you're after:

```
SELECT 
      tc.[ticket_id]
    , [earliest_comment_date] = MIN(tc.[created_on])
    , [latest_comment_date] = MAX(tc.[created_on])
FROM [dbo].[ticket_comment] tc
GROUP BY tc.[ticket_id];
GO
```

The first 10 results:

| ticket_id | earliest_comment_date | latest_comment_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1933-04-30 06:41:10.0000000 +00:00 | 2069-01-16 08:44:14.0000000 +00:00 |
| 2 | 1932-12-28 06:29:54.0000000 +00:00 | 2069-01-05 11:02:08.0000000 +00:00 |
| 3 | 1933-03-22 13:49:08.0000000 +00:00 | 2068-10-26 08:13:15.0000000 +00:00 |
| 4 | 1933-02-27 03:09:17.0000000 +00:00 | 2068-11-20 08:11:17.0000000 +00:00 |
| 5 | 1933-01-29 06:52:08.0000000 +00:00 | 2068-10-19 19:46:35.0000000 +00:00 |
| 6 | 1933-06-20 00:55:59.0000000 +00:00 | 2068-09-26 21:34:51.0000000 +00:00 |
| 7 | 1933-03-01 14:22:34.0000000 +00:00 | 2068-11-14 02:31:51.0000000 +00:00 |
| 8 | 1932-12-20 11:56:56.0000000 +00:00 | 2068-10-27 10:58:30.0000000 +00:00 |
| 9 | 1933-04-07 11:05:45.0000000 +00:00 | 2068-10-04 18:23:10.0000000 +00:00 |
| 10 | 1932-12-23 07:56:50.0000000 +00:00 | 2069-01-16 22:51:31.0000000 +00:00 |

Here's the actual execution plan for the query:  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Skbggjxzh

[image]

The query reads the entire table in a single scan, using a streaming aggregate operator to get the first and last rows out of the `ix_ticket_comment` index, making for very quick execution.

Bumping the number of tickets to 10,000 (with 1,000 comments per ticket for a total of 10,000,000 rows in the `[dbo].[ticket_comment]` table still returns the entire result set in an elapsed time of 672ms on my RedHat VM running on my laptop.  The query uses parallelism over the 4 cores in the VM; here's the statistics for the query:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 402 ms, elapsed time = 402 ms.

(10000 rows affected)
Table 'ticket_comment'. Scan count 5, logical reads 30739, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 2623 ms,  elapsed time = 672 ms.
```

And here's the execution plan:  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkYx7ogM2